# Jquery plugin Dropkick with dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am using the awesome Dropkick plugin to style my dropdownlist in asp.net ,I have imported all the .js ans .css ( not the 'jquery.validate.min.js',I guess it has nothing to do with my problem)... The Dropkick plugin gets implemented but the options in the dropdownlist are not scrollable they are appearing as bullet points... I am not able to figure out what might be wrong with the code... here is my code :

```
Code :
```

Css -DropKick.css

JS -Jquery_1_8_3.js

JS - Dropkick.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.default').dropkick();

The style sheet, the plugin everything is working but the options are not getting rendered correctly they are visible as bullet points and can't be scrolled...

..Plus is there a way to disable the dropdown after activating the Dropkick plugin??

PLEASE HELP!!